# How to find distance to root in MySql tree structured data?

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, database-schema, hierarchical-data

I have a bunch of a data in the following schema:

```
Id | category | remote_id
-------------------------
```

Where remote_id references another ID in the same table.

How can I query this so that for every record, I can find the distance to the root element thats defined as the row where the Id and remote_id are the same?

There is only one root in this data.

Can this be done purely through SQL without modifying this schema? Or is it necessary that I pull the data in memory into some server side application and model it like a conventional tree?

Answer (score 0):

A procedure like this should work, though I haven't tested it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getDistanceToRoot
(
id INT
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE distance INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE parentId INT DEFAULT NULL;
  SET parentId = (SELECT remoteid from table where id = id);
  WHILE (id != parentId) DO
    SET count = count + getDistanceToRoot(parentId);
    SET parentId = (SELECT remoteid from table where id = parentId);
 END WHILE;
  SELECT distance;
END;
```

It will also be slow. You could improve it's performance, once you tweak it to work (like I said I haven't tested it) by saving the distance for each `id` into a different table after getting it, as part of the procedure.

Comment: How can I view the result? What if i wanted to append the answer (distance to root) to a new column for each row? Right now I get an error here that says subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: Also should mention the branching factor of the data is not fixed.

Comment: This procedure definitely will not work.  The idea would work, either as a procedure or function, but not as a hybrid.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why won't it work? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: @AdamBronfin . . . Let's start with the observation that procedures do not return values.